# Seeing error 500 when trying to enable Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome from the Google API console

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

From the Google API Console, when I try to enable the Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome API, I see a 500 error in the javascript console:

`POST https://cloud.google.com/console/m/api/apilist/682126721867?xsrf=aBdPrU16rlpKR6KsWi-IrXjPQe4:1387559908732 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Google: how do I get this enabled?!